# program that simulates queuing and service by requests at a fast food restaurant

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

I was asked to code a program without using any data structure libraries.

Inputs are:

- The number of primary servers in the system.
- The number of secondary servers in the system.
- A set of service requests each consisting of an arrival time and two service times.
- This set is terminated by a dummy record with arrival time and service times all equal to 0. (Note: the arrival times are sorted in ascending order).

I'm quite new to java so I would like to get advice what's the best way of doing this or resources which would help me understand the concept better.

I know we do need to create 2 Queues, one for the primary and secondary server to store the data while they are waiting to be served. 
I probably have to create counters to increment and decrement for the time. Hopefully my thought process is right.

But I'm unsure how do we go about creating multiple Queues and what data structure i would use for the servers.

Answer (score 0):

The way to approach this problem is to draw a diagram of the real-world situation. Customers come in and line up. There are X servers, each of which can handle one customer at a time. Also model the role of the secondary servers, whatever it is.

Then start handling transactions: server engages customer, passes order to secondary server queue and waits. Gets response from secondary server, finishes with customer, etc. Describe every place where information is exchanged between customers, servers, and secondary servers.

If you do that, you have a very good understanding of the problem you're trying to solve, and a real-world solution. Then you just have to model that in code. Your best bet is to first write a basic outline in pseudocode that describes the data structures and algorithms you're going to use. Once you have that, you can simulate its operation by (again) resorting to pencil and paper.

When you're convinced that you have the algorithm right, *then* you sit down to write code. And writing the code is pretty much a straightforward translation of your pseudocode.